# Making overnight bagels - may have underkneaded, can I knead it tomorrow?

Tags: kneading, bagels

It's my first time ever making bagels. I followed [this](https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/homemade-cinnamon-raisin-bagels/) recipe with the overnight alteration.  I kneaded for about 10-12 minutes.  After trying the pull test, it kind of breaks before becoming translucent.  It has been in the refrigerator for some time now.  My question is whether I can knead them in the morning until they pass the pull test or should I bake them as is?

Comment: If you *really* want to re-knead it, I’d recommend shaping half the dough without kneading, then lightly kneading the rest and shaping.  This way, you can compare the two, and decide what you like better.  It’s difficult to judge when you haven’t made a recipe before what each stage is supposed to look like.  Or divide in thirds, and really knead one part, but then it won’t get as much rest before boiling and might be even worse

Answer (score 7):

The given recipe is a very dry one - the author points it out herself - and it’s hard to get a good windowpane test with a low-hydration dough.

Gluten develops in two ways, either by kneading or over time when the flour comes together with water. An extreme example that relies only on the latter are no-knead types of bread.

In your case, the overnight rise should be enough to give you the desired gluten structure. Would probably bake them as is, only if especially large holes have formed would I do a quick re-knead, just to break them up.